# Change height of UITableView which is in custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a tableview which is `inside a custom class UIView.` This custom UIView is then added to a different UIViewController. `If I change the height of the table view inside the xib file then it corresponds and changes when the app is run.` I am trying to programatically change the height of this tableview though depending on how many cells it has.

Normally i would do a `tableview.frame=CGRectMake(15,29,290,height)` and this would change the size but it does not seem to be working.

I have also tried the `[tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(15,29,290,height)];` and this also doesnt work. I have tried it inside the method in the custom uiview that sets up the custom view and I have have also tried it within the UIViewController of which the view is added. Here is my code in the UIViewController that adds the custom uiview.

```
    LeagueInvites* invitedView =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InvitedView"
                                                               owner:nil
                                                             options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [invitedView setUpLeagueInvite:allInvites :obj.nUserName];
    invitedView.frame=CGRectMake(0, (615 +height), 320, 29+([allInvites count]*120));
    [invitedView.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 29, 290, 400)];
    [self.fullScroll addSubview:invitedView];
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the container view that the table view is in has enough height to house the new height of the table view?

Comment: @rocky yes it is, when I manually manually make the table view larger inside the view it works, its just programmatically it does not seem to respond

Comment: after you set the frame, query the frame and does it match with what you set it to?

Comment: the frame matches what i enter programatically, but this does not reflect to what is happening actually happening on screen. It says the view is 240 but the actual view on the app is only 120

Comment: hmmmm did you check the AutoLayout settings on that view?

Comment: I am not using autolayout

Comment: OK. If you set the height to 440 is the actual 220? Just trying to see if its halving it

Comment: nope its not halving it, the size stays the same

Comment: is the table view initially set at 120 in the nib?

Comment: yes it is, the view is just scrolling as opposed to getting taller, is this potentially something to do with the frame/layout size not being the same?

Comment: solved it! it was to do with the tablecell footer and header both set to 1, so i just decreased the size of the tablecell by 2 and it worked. thanks for your patience rocky!